Shaft torque analysis VS vibration analysis in predictive maintenance
I have a dynamic torque sensor that can measure the torque my electric motor is exerting. I also have a vibration and temperature sensor. My problem is this: I want to know what the advantages of the torque sensor would be for predictive maintenance. Basically, I'd like to know what kind of problems could be identified by torque analysis that couldn't be identified by vibration? The first advantage I see would be the fact that the torque wrench can be used for motors that run at low speed. But what are the other advantages?

Predicting fatigue life I suppose. Vibration would only pick that up as the shaft was failing.

I feel like torque sensors are for process issues.  I suppose you could see a high friction condition, but it seems like the process would be a bigger impact.
